# Dapper SQL Server Update fails with error "The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports maximum of 2100 parameters"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I am getting the below error when using dapper SQL Server update execution.

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request

Code:

```
IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> objReturn = null;

var employeeQuery = @"Select employee_id,employee_name from DBO.Employee where IsActive in ('Y')";

this.EmplDBConnection.open();
var employeeList = await. this.EmplDBConnection.QueryAsync<EmployeeModel>(employeeQuery);
    
EmplDBConnection.Execute("Update DBO.employee set IsActive = @Employee_Status where employee_id in @Employee_Id,
    new {@Employee_Status = IsActive, Employee_Id = employeeList.Select(x => x.employee_id});
this.EmplDBConnection.Close();
```

Comment: try breaking your code like this `string updateQuery = "Update DBO.employee set IsActive = @Employee_Status where employee_id in @Employee_Ids";

var param = new
{
    Employee_Status = IsActive,
    Employee_Ids = employeeList.Select(x => x.employee_id)
};

this.EmplDBConnection.Execute(updateQuery, param);
` just notice I have `IN` in query

Comment: There's no reason to open the connection before calling `QueryAsync` or `ExecuteAsync`. Dapper will do this itself. As for the error, it's pretty clear - you can't use more than 2100 items in an `IN` clause, nor should you want to. You can use a `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` query. In this case you seem to only need the EmployeeIDs, not the entire row

Comment: What is this code trying to do? Change the value of *all* active employees to something else?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you share the sample code for my issue if you don't mind?

Comment: @JSLover what *is* the issue? What is this trying to do? The first query loads all active employees. The second tries to modify the *same* rows, setting the original values except `IsActive`. You could replace all of it with `UPDATE Employees SET IsActive='You got Fired' WHERE IsActive ='Y'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean:

```cs
employeeList.Select(x=> new {
    Employee_Status = IsActive,
    Employee_Id = x.employee_id})
```

as the args parameter. Dapper will unroll the generated sequence and issue one command per employee.

Note, however, that a single `in` query may be more performant. But since you seem to be getting the input *from* the DB: it feels like you can do all of this without even fetching anything. maybe just an execute, without a query, something like:

```
update DBO.Employee
set IsActive = -- your input needed here
where IsActive = 'Y'
```

Comment: It's unclear if `IN` is needed at all. This code seems to be trying to change the status of all active employees to something else. Which ... is scary. `UPDATE EMployees SET IsActive='Not Y' WHERE IsActive ='Y'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I was saying the same thing in an edit. The OP's operation here is very ... odd